How do I transfer a BluetoothSocket from one activity to another?
In my Android app, I've set up two activities:

Connection Activity: This activity helps find and connect to
Bluetooth devices. It shows a list of both paired and discoverable
devices.

Control Activity: Once connected, I want to use this
activity to send and receive data with the Bluetooth device. The
issue I am facing is how to get the established connection
(represented by the BluetoothSocket object) from the connection
activity to the control activity.


What's the recommended method to this?
(Please provide some tutorials about the method if possible)

I think you can use a service to establish the Bluetooth connection within a service and bind both activities to that service. with that service, the connection persists across activity transitions.
Here is the tutorial about Bluetooth: https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth
